Proof: Under what conditions does a Markov Chain have a stationary distribution?
For a (discrete time) markov chain, a stationary distribution $π$ is a probability distribution that satisfies (where $P$ is the transition probability matrix of the Markov chain):
$$ \pi = \pi P $$
I am trying to understand why a (discrete time) markov chain needs to be irreducible (1) and positive recurrent (2) for a stationary distribution to exist.

(1) Irreducibility
I think this can be shown by contradiction.
An irreducible Markov chain is one where it's possible to get from any state to any other state in a finite number of steps.
Assume we have a reducible Markov chain that has a stationary distribution. Being reducible means there are at least two closed communicating classes, let's call them $A$ and $B$.
Let $\pi$ be the supposed stationary distribution. We can split $\pi$ into two parts:
$$ \pi = (\pi_A, \pi_B) $$
where $\pi_A$ corresponds to the states in $A$ and $\pi_B$ to the states in $B$.
Since $A$ and $B$ are closed and don't communicate with each other, we can write the transition probability matrix $P$ in block form:
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 
P_A & 0 \\
0 & P_B
\end{bmatrix} $$
For $\pi$ to be stationary, we must have:
$$ (\pi_A, \pi_B) = (\pi_A, \pi_B) \begin{bmatrix} 
P_A & 0 \\
0 & P_B
\end{bmatrix} $$
This implies:
$$ \pi_A = \pi_A P_A $$
$$ \pi_B = \pi_B P_B $$
But this means that $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ are themselves stationary distributions for the sub-chains A and B.
However, for $\pi$ to be a proper probability distribution, we must have:
$$ \sum_{i \in A} \pi_i + \sum_{j \in B} \pi_j = 1 $$
This is only possible if either $\sum_{i \in A} \pi_i = 0$ or $\sum_{j \in B} \pi_j = 0$ (or both), because $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ are themselves probability distributions that sum to 1.
But if either sum is zero, then that part of the chain has no probability mass in the stationary distribution, which contradicts the definition of a stationary distribution (which should assign non-zero probability to all recurrent states).

(2) Positive Recurrent
This is the part where I am struggling with.
In a discrete time markov chain , a state $i$ is positive recurrent if the expected return time to state $i$, starting from state $i$, is finite. If we define $T_i$ as the return time to state $i$, then state $i$ is positive recurrent if:
$$ E[T_i | X_0 = i] < \infty $$
Thus it would seem to me that if all states in a markov chain satisfy this condition, the markov chain is positive recurrent.
From here, I defined:

$X_n$: the state of the Markov chain at time $n$
$T_i = \min\{n > 0: X_n = i | X_0 = i\}$: the first return time to state $i$
$f_i^{(n)} = P(T_i = n)$: the probability of first return to state $i$ at time $n$
$V_i(N)$: the number of visits to state $i$ in $N$ steps
$R_i(k)$: the time of the $k$-th return to state $i$

Using some well known properties of Markov Chains.

For a stationary distribution $\pi$ (e.g. if in $n$ = 100 steps you visit state $i$ 3 times, the average probability of being in state $i$ is 0.03 - and this is what a stationary distribution is when $n$ becomes large):

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{V_i(N)}{N} = \pi_i $$
This follows from the definition of $\pi_i$ as the long-run proportion of time spent in state $i$.

For the expected number of visits:

$$ E[V_i(N)] = N\pi_i $$
This is because $\pi_i$ is the probability of being in state $i$ at any given time in the long run.

Expected time between returns (the Markov property: each return is independent of previous returns):

$$ E[R_i(k) - R_i(k-1)] = E[T_i] $$
We can infer the number of visits to return times:
$$ V_i(N) = \max\{k : R_i(k) \leq N\} $$
This says the number of visits in $N$ steps equals the maximum number of returns possible within $N$ steps.
Using Law of Large Numbers, as $N \to \infty$ (and consequently $k \to \infty$):
$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{R_i(k)}{k} = E[T_i] $$
Using the above results, for large $N$ (e.g. if in 100 steps you returned to state $i$ 3 times, then on average it took 33.3 steps to return each time):
$$ \frac{N}{V_i(N)} \approx E[T_i] $$
Taking the limit as $N \to \infty$ and using the earlier result:
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{N}{V_i(N)} = \frac{1}{\pi_i} = E[T_i] $$
Therefore:
$$ \pi_i = \frac{1}{E[T_i]} $$
For $\pi_i$ to exist and be positive (which it must be for all recurrent states in a stationary distribution), $E[T_i]$ must be finite (i.e. non-zero and not infinity).
Thus, we can see that a Markov Chain needs to positive recurrent for it to have a stationary distribution.

Is my work correct?


Mini result 1: The expected number of visits to state $i$ in a very long run of $N$ steps is $N\pi_i$.

We know that $\pi_i$ is the stationary probability of being in state $i$. In the long run, it represents the proportion of time the chain spends in state $i$.
Define a random variable $X_t$ for each step $t$:
$$ X_t = \begin{cases} 
   1 & \text{if the chain is in state i at step t} \\
   0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} $$
The expected value of $X_t$ for any $t$ (in the long run) is:
$$ E[X_t] = 1 \cdot P(X_t = 1) + 0 \cdot P(X_t = 0) = P(X_t = 1) = \pi_i $$
Now, let's define $Y$ as the total number of visits to state $i$ in $N$ steps:
$$ Y = \sum_{t=1}^N X_t $$
By the linearity of expectation:
$$ E[Y] = E[\sum_{t=1}^N X_t] = \sum_{t=1}^N E[X_t] $$
Since $E[X_t] = \pi_i$ for all $t$ (in the long run):
$$ E[Y] = \sum_{t=1}^N \pi_i = N\pi_i $$
This result, $E[Y] = N\pi_i$, tells us that in a very long run of $N$ steps, we expect to visit state $i$ approximately $N\pi_i$ times.


Mini result 2: Average time between visits to state $i$ in the long run is equal to the expected first return time.

We can define the expected first return time as:
$$ E[T_i] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n f_i^{(n)} $$

$E[T_i]$ is the expected return time to state $i$.
$f_i^{(n)}$ is the probability of first return to state $i$ at exactly time $n$, given that we started in state $i$.
The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n f_i^{(n)}$ is the definition of the expected first return time (i.e. definition of expectation for a discrete random variable_

If we consider a very long run of the Markov chain. Let's divide this run into cycles, where each cycle starts when we enter state $i$ and ends just before we enter state $i$ again. These cycles are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) because of the Markov property. Each cycle length has the same distribution as the first return time.
By the Law of Large Numbers, as the number of cycles goes to infinity, the average cycle length converges to the expected cycle length, which is $E[T_i]$.
Thus, if we have $N$ cycles in our long run, and $L$ is the total length of the run:
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{L}{N} = E[T_i] $$
But $\frac{L}{N}$ is precisely the average time between visits to state $i$ in this long run.
Therefore, in the long run, the average time between visits to state $i$ converges to the expected first return time $E[T_i]$.

It does not have to be irreducible, but then the stationary distribution may be not unique, e.g. consider two-state chain with $P=[[1,0],[0,1]]$.
